# In which area using OSGI make sense?

Tags: java, osgi, artificial-intelligence, platform

I am trying to learn about OSGI. It seems it is made for creating a smart system like a smart home, IoT stuff. Is there any other use case for OSGI? OSGI for analytic platform or AI system would make sense? 
Sorry my question is really naive.

Comment: OSGI is not restricted to any application area. You can use it anywhere, where you need something like a "plugin system" or a "module system".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the most important feature of OSGi is the ability to plug/unplug a code module at runtime without stopping the JVM, so the other modules (unless dependent from the plugged/unplugged one) continue to run.

Example, Liferay Portal (7.0+) is built on OSGi because it needs to add/remove features and applications at runtime without interrupting the portal itself. 
While, instead, if you need to add a library (even an SPI) to a Spring app, you at least have to stop it, add the dependency in the pom, compile and run again.

There are other advantages in using OSGi (modularity and encapsulation are the key points) but in my opinion this is the main one and I don't know any other java technology that does this.

Anyway, better know that OSGi is not a piece of cake. These advantages have a drawback in a steep learning curve and a lot of try-and-error.
So, in my opinion, the use of OSGi should be carefully evaluated taking all into account.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you prefer using OSGI SpringBoot , maven together ?

Comment: SpringBoot is, in my opinion, altenative to OSGi, as a SpringBoot App runs through its "main" method (so, launching a new JVM process). But it is possibile to build an OSGi bundle (the modules in OSGi are called "bundles") based on Spring. In this case the easiest (eventhough not "pure" OSGi) solution is to add Spring libraries as dependencies in the pom and build a jar (a bundle is a jar with the correct MANIFEST.MF). The Spring context creation have to be called in the Activator (the method that the OSGi runtime, e.g. Apache Karaf, calls when a new bundle is loaded, resolved and started).

Comment: The official site is this: https://www.osgi.org/developer/where-to-start/ They recommend the enRoute tutorial, but if you had already selected a runtime (Equinox, Felix, Karaf...) I'd start from its pages, because some runtimes have extended/integrated the OSGi specifications (example: Eclipse Equinox did).
This is a good tutorial (based on Equinox) I recommend: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html
In any case, this is THE developer tool for programming in OSGi: https://bnd.bndtools.org/ which comes also as an extension for Eclipse.